# Android - OnPreExecute check if I need to do another AsyncTask first

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

In the onPreExecute method of my AsyncTask 'A' I want to check if I need to carry out another AsyncTask 'B' first. If I do, I want to run B before the doInBackground of A.

Can I do this? Is there a better way to implement this logic?

EDIT: Let me expand my question. If I have several AsyncTasks A, C and D and I want to check if I need to carry out B in each of these tasks, how can I do that? Essentially I want to extend the functionality of the AsyncTask and inherit from that, but it becomes tricky with the generic types used in AsyncTask.

Comment: Why not check first if you need to run B before calling async task A's execute method?

Comment: In a lot of my async tasks I need to do this one check so I think I would like to extend the functionality of Async task and check this. I don't want to have to add the check into a lot of places

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is independent.Once you run it,you can not get it back.
Unless...
You can create a list(or map) manage these task.

For example,

```
Class AsyncManager {
   Map manager = mManager;

  void putAsyTask(AsyncTask at) {
       mManager.put(key,at);//you should decide the key
  }
  void checkExisted(Object key) {
     //check key is in mManager
  }
}
```

and in onPreExecute,you can check the task whether in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Within the method doInBackground tasks run **synchronously**, then you can do the validation in **doInBackground** method:

```
doInBackground(...){

  if(needExecuteTaskB){
     //Task B...
  }

  //Task A...

  return;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Let me expand on my question. If I want to implement this check across several of my AsyncTasks I think I want to extend the AsyncTask, override the doInBackground method and add my functionality and call super.doInBackground in my concrete AsyncTask. But this is tricky with the generic types that are different for a lot of the classes I use. How can I solve this problem?